# this.$router is undefined inside Vue.extend() method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Using vue v2.5.9 and vue-router v.3.0.1.

Minimal reproduction link: https://codepen.io/clarewhatever/pen/eyzMNo

I am trying to dynamically insert a `<router-link>` element into component using the `Vue.extend()` method.

```js
Vue.component('markdown', {
  name: 'markdown',
  props: {
    routeName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    routeLabel: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: `<span ref="content"></span>`,
  mounted () {
    let self = this;
    let routerLink = `<router-link :to="{ name: ${routeName} }">${routeLabel}</router-link>`;
    let MarkdownContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `<div>${routerLink}</div>`,
      // router: self.$router,
      mounted () {
        // this.$router is undefined unless router is explicitly defined
        console.log(this.$router);
      }
    });
    new MarkdownContent().$mount(this.$refs.content);
  }
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that `this.$router` is undefined within the `extend()` method so the route being passed to the router-link does not exist. If I pass in the router from the parent component (`router: self.$router`) the router-link element mounts as expected.

I tried swapping out `Vue.extend()` for `Vue.component()` but ran into the same issue. I think it must have something to do with the `vm.$mount` method being called on a constructor, although I'm not sure why it works that way. All of the docs show it being used that way, but I haven't been able to find an example that includes vue-router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating a new Vue instance and mounting it, via `new MarkdownContent().$mount(...)`, you are breaking the normal paradigm of parent/child relationship. The VueRouter plugin automatically sets the reference for `this.$router` for child components included in the template. But, by manually mounting the component, you lose that reference.

Instantiating and mounting a new component just to render a `<router-link>` tag seems very roundabout. But, if you really need do it this way, you just need to specify the `router` reference in the component definition object:

```
let MarkdownContent = Vue.extend({
  router,
  template: `<div>${routerLink}</div>`,
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$router);
  }
});
```

[Here's a working codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eogaro)

Comment: I think your CodePen might be broken, but I understand what you're saying. Thank you for the clarification about why the router has to be redefined on the new Vue instance.

I am mounting a new component just to render a `<router-link>` component because the data is coming from an async call. The data is coming back as markdown and I am using markdown-it to parse the content and render the HTML. I've written an extension to detect internal links, which get rendered as router-links. Because they are created after the component is mounted they don't get parsed properly by the component.

Comment: The codepen is working fine for me, what's not working for you? And why can't you render the `<router-link>` right in the template of Component B?

Comment: I'm seeing the page continually reload. I updated my above comment to include reasoning for approaching it this way.

Comment: Update: I opened the link in an incognito window and it's working fine, must be an extension I have installed. Thank you!